# Why does golang bytes.Buffer behave in such way?

Tags: string, csv, go

I recently faced a problem, where I'm writing to a `byte.Buffer` using a `writer`. But when I do `String()` on that `byte.Buffer` I'm getting an unexpected output (extra pair of double quotes added). Can you please help me understand it?

Here is a code snippet of my problem! I just need help understanding why each word is surrounded by a double quote.

```golang
func main() {
    var csvBuffer bytes.Buffer
    wr := csv.NewWriter(&csvBuffer)
    data := []string{`{"agent":"python-requests/2.19.1","api":"/packing-slip/7123"}`}
    err := wr.Write(data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("WARNING: unable to write ", err)
    }
    wr.Flush()
    fmt.Println(csvBuffer.String())
}
```

**Output:**

> {""agent"":""python-requests/2.19.1"",""api"":""/packing-slip/7123""}

Comment: this is a csv escape thingy, nothing to do with bytes.Buffer I believe. Basically two double quotes next to each other in csv means one double quote in "reality". This is explained in the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) of the package you're using.

Comment: true ! I feel the same. Im just finding it hard to understand that escape thing.

Comment: csv is a standard, see [rfc4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) (section 2.7) if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CSV double quotes (`"`) are escaped as 2 double quotes. That's what you see.

You encode a single `string` value which contains double quotes, so all those are replaced with 2 double quotes.

When decoded, the result will contain 1 double quotes of course:

```
r := csv.NewReader(&csvBuffer)
rec, err := r.Read()
fmt.Println(rec, err)
```

Outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GnPlkTTF5Zo)):

```
[{"agent":"python-requests/2.19.1","api":"/packing-slip/7e0a05b3"}] <nil>
```

Quoting from package doc of [`encoding/csv`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/):

> Within a quoted-field a quote character followed by a second quote character is considered a single quote.
>
> ```
> "the ""word"" is true","a ""quoted-field"""
> ```
>
> results in
>
> ```
> {`the "word" is true`, `a "quoted-field"`}
> ```

In CSV, the following are equivalent:

```
one,two
```

and

```
"one","two"
```

Now if the values would contain double quotes, that would indicate the end of the value. CSV handles this by substituting double quotes with 2 of them. The value `one"1` is encoded as `one""1` in CSV, e.g.:

```
"one""1","two""2"
```

Comment: Thanks icza, This really made sense.Thanks for helping me understand it with an example.